# Backbone and Laravel: Prevent access to Laravel controller method

Tags: url, backbone.js, controller, laravel

First of all, sorry for my bad english language skills.

I am using Laravel and Backbone.js for small web app. In my backbone collection I'am defining urlRoot: 'test/cont1'. How can I "allow" backbone to asynchronously go to that URL but prevent user to manually go to the same URL by typing it in web browser (User will then get some json response that i don't want for him to see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you want but you could add a filter and simply do `if ( ! Request::ajax()) App::abort();`

**EDIT:** a better example...

```
Route::filter('api', function($route, $request)
{
    if ( ! $request->ajax()) App::abort(404);
});
```

Then in your controllers add the api filter.

Comment: Thank you for respone! Nice one, that trows MethodNotAllowedHttpException  exception to user. Better then valuable json data (it's not that valuable:) )

Comment: That's not the exception it should be throwing though :/ Change it to App::abort(404); and see if you get a proper 404 instead. I'll update the answer.